# stratified 10 fold cross validation in java

Tags: java

I have made a start to create some training and test sets using 10 fold crossvalidation for high dimensional dataset:

```
Dataset[] folds = data.folds((10), new Random(100));
        Dataset training = new DefaultDataset();
        Dataset testing = new DefaultDataset();
        int[] tr = {0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; 
        int[] te = {1};  
        for (int i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            training.addAll(folds[tr[i]]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < te.length; i++) {
            testing.addAll(folds[te[i]]);
        }
```

could some one correct me if am wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Did this mystery person give you a reason for this?

Comment: thanks@JoeC. No, that is why am confused.

Comment: please help because i am running of time

Comment: You really need to go back to the person who told you this and ask them.